# Not able to call angular resource factory save method

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am using angular resource factory to creates a resource object that let me  interact with RESTful server as given below. But when i initiate userService it gives error

> TypeError: userService is not a constructor

**Factory**

```
angular.module('App')
.factory('userService', function($resource) {
   var user;

  return $resource('/app/user/:id'),{
     'setUser': function (user) {
     this.user=user;
     },

     'getUser': function () {
     return this.user;
     }
     } /// Note the full endpoint address

});
```

I tried lot of ways but not able to create object. My controller code is

**Controller**

```
            $scope.user = new userService(); 
            $scope.user.data = $scope.newUser;
            userService.save($scope.user);
```

I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The answer I originally provided was incorrect. I actually had no idea you could "new" a resource.

It looks like the syntax for defining a resource is not correct, see this example for the AngularJS docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

```
// Define a CreditCard class
var CreditCard = $resource('/users/:userId/cards/:cardId',
  {userId: 123, cardId: '@id'}, {
    charge: {method: 'POST', params: {charge: true}}
});
```

You are actually returning a resource and an object separated by a comma.
In your case is your factory userService is actually just returning

```
{
     'setUser': function (user) {
     this.user=user;
     },

     'getUser': function () {
     return this.user;
     }
}
```

And then you are trying to new this.

This is happening because your return is actually using the "comma" operator in javascript separating the actual resource and the object itself. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

The comma operator will evaluate each of its operands and return the last one. In this case your actions object.

I don't even think you seed that actions object as to set / get properties of a resource you can just modify the resource properties.

so instead of

`$scope.user.$setUser({foo:'bar'});`

You can just do

`$scope.user = {foo:'bar'}

If you need to do complex modifications to resources I would instead make services / factories that can modify your resources for you.

tl;dr

change your return to

`return $resource('/app/user/:id');`

if you really want to add methods to this, you can do so on the prototype

```
var resource = $resource('/app/user/:id');

resource.prototype.getUser = function(){
  return this.user;
}

return resource;
```

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Well to use the method of $resource factory, we can create object and call save, delete etc methods as given in link

https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/

Every thing working fine when i write factory as below with same controller code
**Factory**
 `return $resource('/app/user/:id')`

But when i add another custom methods as shown in problem description ,it throws error **TypeError: userService is not a constructor**

Comment: I have updated my answer, I had no idea you could new a resource like that and it threw me off the actual problem you were having. TIL